# Cannot receive websocket message using nestjs

Tags: javascript, websocket, nestjs

I am new to websocket, I am trying to use nestjs to make a simple chat service, but I can’t receive and listen to messages through the emit and on methods. I don’t know what went wrong

#### server code:

```
import {
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
  OnGatewayInit,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WsResponse,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Socket } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class AppGateway
  implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
  private logger: Logger = new Logger('AppGateway');

  @SubscribeMessage('msgToServe')
  handleMessage(client: Socket, text: string): WsResponse<string> {
    console.log('text', text);
    return {
      event: 'msgToClient',
      data: 'hello',
    };
  }
  afterInit(server: any): any {
    this.logger.log('init');
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]): any {
    this.logger.log(`connected---${client.id}`);
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket): any {
    this.logger.log(`disconnect---${client.id}`);
  }
}
```

#### client code:

```
const log = console.log;

window.onload = function() {
  // init
  const socket = io('ws://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('msgToClient', data=>{
        log('data: ', data);
        
    })
  socket.emit('msgToServe','123')

  window.socket = socket;
};
```

#### terminal

```
[Nest] 4902   - 01/30/2021, 2:43:23 PM   [AppGateway] disconnect---1WlkfHu_dJpjoWoOAAA0
[Nest] 4902   - 01/30/2021, 2:43:29 PM   [AppGateway] connected---xOxZ39G-tB7AkAXRAAA6
[Nest] 4902   - 01/30/2021, 2:43:29 PM   [AppGateway] disconnect---PuNQJZDVwa-AYPIZAAA1
[Nest] 4902   - 01/30/2021, 2:43:35 PM   [AppGateway] disconnect---jKK78bjktdM5d2knAAA2
[Nest] 4902   - 01/30/2021, 2:43:35 PM   [AppGateway] connected---RUoKEpjUkNKUUTWXAAA7
[Nest] 4902   - 01/30/2021, 2:43:41 PM   [AppGateway] disconnect---L4DY0OHQ_1-SBvZrAAA3
[Nest] 4902   - 01/30/2021, 2:43:41 PM   [AppGateway] connected---rz14IHszXM0UoihXAAA8
[Nest] 4902   - 01/30/2021, 2:43:47 PM   [AppGateway] connected---MI6o_DcXCGRUju6DAAA9
[Nest] 4902   - 01/30/2021, 2:43:47 PM   [AppGateway] disconnect---Psmjt4VIN1FUpAGNAAA4
[Nest] 4902   - 01/30/2021, 2:43:53 PM   [AppGateway] disconnect---EknXjm7lXQ5_l1xdAAA5
[Nest] 4902   - 01/30/2021, 2:43:53 PM   [AppGateway] connected---BXKO9NS5K31V2siOAAA-
[Nest] 4902   - 01/30/2021, 2:43:59 PM   [AppGateway] disconnect---xOxZ39G-tB7AkAXRAAA6
[Nest] 4902   - 01/30/2021, 2:43:59 PM   [AppGateway] connected---8-eOObbqxvALfDJFAAA_
[Nest] 4902   - 01/30/2021, 2:44:05 PM   [AppGateway] disconnect---RUoKEpjUkNKUUTWXAAA7
```

The terminal did not receive any messages, I don’t know what went wrong

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, even though I am using socket.io version 2.4.1. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: For anyone dealing with ngx-socket-io on the client side, the current latest version of ngx-socket-io (4.0.0) uses socket.io v3, which as explained by @antoineso is not compatible witn NestJS. You can use     "ngx-socket-io": "^3.2.0" to fix it.

Comment: Hello, it is beed a while, did you manage to solve this issue, can you share the sollution with us please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I supposed that you are using socket io v3 and this version is not compatible with Nestjs for now
according to this [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5676) on NestJs gitHub Repository.
Two solutions:

1. downgrade socket io version to v2.
2. If you can't downgrade you can do what it's explain in the github issue  by creating a [socket io adapter](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5676#issuecomment-749719792) and add it to your **Main.ts** like this:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  // ...
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new SocketIoAdapter(app, corsOrigins));
}
```